# Encrypt and decrypt Non varchar column in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, encryption

I've searched around and did some tests, but I can't seem to find a way to encrypt and decrypt a column that is not of varchar datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_ENCRYPT (
 TEST_STRING VARCHAR(255),
 TEST_INT INT 
 )

INSERT INTO TEMP_ENCRYPT (TEST_STRING, TEST_INT) VALUES
(DES_ENCRYPT('valor string', '1234'), DES_ENCRYPT('56', '1234'))


select
 TEST_STRING as a,
 DES_DECRYPT(TEST_STRING, '1234') as aa,
 TEST_INT as b,
 DES_DECRYPT(TEST_INT, '1234') as bb
from TEMP_ENCRYPT
```

This select returns

a               |     aa        |  b    | bb

ÿ£ßû↵gê Tïë¦ß | valor string  |  0  |  0

This seems to be a basic thing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DES_ENCRYPT('56', '1234')` will result in `/+nNpdXyewki`, which can't be stored in a column intended for integers, so it'll (depending on your settings) either get stored as `0` or throw a warning. If you want to store encrypted data, you'll need to store it in a column that supports strings.

Comment: really? That seems like a handicap, no?

Comment: @franmcod Not in any way that isn't already an issue with row-level encryption already.